# XML query with parameter (SSRS/SHAREPOINT)

Tags: xml, sharepoint, reporting-services

Using SQL Server 2014, I have SSRS report which connects to Microsoft SharePoint List.
The query looks like:

```
<RSSharePointList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ListName>Journaltasks</ListName>
  <ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name="Title" />
    <FieldRef Name="Status" />
    <FieldRef Name="Project" />
  </ViewFields>
  <Query>
    <Where><Membership Type='SPGroup' ID='15'><FieldRef Name='AssignedTo'/></Membership></Where>
  </Query>
</RSSharePointList>
```

The part of query where value **15**, I need to change it on value of my report parameter **ReportGroupID**. Hope for help with syntax of this xml query.